# Pandas: How to filter another dataframe on a groupby custom function argument?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframe as below,

```
df1
      scale
name  
a     10
b     20
c     30

df2
            c1    c2
id  name  
a   aa      1     4
b   bb      2     5
c   cc      3     6
```

I want to do a groupby on the `df2` based on a custom func which takes the value from `df1`. That is,

```
def myfun(c, s):
    # do some complex maths but simplified below
    return c * s
```

I wanted to do something like below,

```
df = df2.groupby(['id','name'].agg(myfunc, s=df1.loc[<somehow replace this with name in this group>]['scale'])
```

Note: I am working on a huge dataset, so I get oom when I send the entire df1 into myfunc.

Comment: have you considered moving away from pandas? e.g. to dask https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html

Comment: Thanks @matt. Indeed I am using dask with map partitions.

Comment: I just want one value from df1 in the myfunc as per the grouped column.